# How do i fix Unresolved attribute reference 'send_message' for class 'Bot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am building a discord bot, and would like to be able to send a message to the discord server after someone has deleted a message.

I have tried to re-install discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    author = message.author
    content = message.content
    channel = message.channel
    await client.send_message(channel, author, content)
```

The result I am expecting is a message with the author and content that was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to remember when using [on_message_delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete) is that the messages get enqueued into `Client.messages` after the bot is up running so you can't detect the deletion of older messages

Also [send_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message) doesn't have an `author` parameter

What you could to, to document who sent what in the deleted message is something like this

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
  author = message.author
  content = message.content
  channel = message.channel
  await client.send_message(channel,f"{author.mention} : {content}")
```